# Problem while creating new Bundle using Core service of existing bundle 'Metadata Type' schema

Tags: core-service, bundles

While creating bundle using core service I am getting following exception:
Unable to find http://www.mycompanyname.com/tridion/schema/prodpublish_bundle_schema:Metadata.

I am following below process:

1. Reading what type (prod publish or prod unpublish) of bundle I have to create.

   ```
   SchemaData bundleSchema =(SchemaData)TridionCoreServiceFactory
        .CreateCoreService().Read("tcm:222-21051-8", _ReadOption);
   ```
2. getting Virtual folder type scheam as Bundle

   ```
   SchemaData virtualFolderTypeSchema = TridionCoreServiceFactory.CreateCoreService()
        .GetVirtualFolderTypeSchema(@"http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/Bundle");
   ```
3. Creating new VirtualFolder and setting propties to make it Bundle

   ```
   VirtualFolderData bundle = new VirtualFolderData()
   {
       MetadataSchema = new LinkToSchemaData(){IdRef = bundleSchema.Id},
       TypeSchema = new LinkToSchemaData(){IdRef = virtualFolderTypeSchema.Id},
       //setting other properties like name ,description, location etc. 
   }
   ```

With the above code Core Service is trying to find namesapce used in provided MetadataSchema and ending with error

> Unable to find
>   http://www.mycompanyname.com/tridion/schema/prodpublish_bundle_schema:Metadata.

When I checked source of BundleType  'prodpublish_bundle' it really has thenamespace

```
  <xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.mycompanyname.com/tridion/schema/prodpublish_bundle_schema"
    xmlns:tcmi="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0/Instance"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
```

targetNamespace="http://www.mycompanyname.com/tridion/schema/prodpublish_bundle_schema">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set the Metadata schema, but not the Metadata itself. If metadata schema is set you should always set the metadata as well, even if schema has no mandatory fields. It should at least contain the namespace, of the metadata schema.

Comment: Hi Andrey,   I followed example code from Tridion Docs http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/ and and your post http://amarchuk.blogspot.com/2013/04/create-update-bundle-through-coreservice.html  but didn't see if I need to set Metadata also. Could you please provide an example of how to set that.

Comment: Metadata schema is optional. If you want it - create bundle with this schema manually and copy it from there